# Sending and receiving Bytes over Android socket two issues:

Tags: java, android, sockets, byte

I've got an issue with JAVA/ Android studio surrounding sending and receiving bytes.
Notably: sending and receiving byte values over 127 using TCP sockets.

I receive data here:

```
    try {
        mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        mBufferIn = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[64];

        while (mRun) {
mBufferIn.read(buffer);
            mServerMessage = String.valueOf(buffer);
            if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
            }
            mServerMessage = null;
        }
```

and send data here:

```
public void sendMessage(final char[] message) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mBufferOut != null) {
                    mBufferOut.write(message);
                    mBufferOut.flush();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
```

When I receive data, all data over 127 in values is returned as "231, 191, 189".
When I send data, every byte with a value x over 127 is returned as "195, x".

How can I cleanly solve this issue?

Comment: `all data over 127 in values is returned as "231, 191, 189".` Well what do you mean? They are all three above 127. And then you did not tel what you sent. You should have started with it.

Comment: @blackapps, That's just it. I send a byte with a value over 127, and in place of that byte, I get three bytes "231, 191, 189" on the receiving end.... no matter which value over 127 I send.

Comment: If you're sending binary why are you using a `Writer`? You should be using an `OutputStream`.

Comment: That is pretty unbelievable. Please show how you call sendMessage(final char[] message).

Comment: As said: dont use Readers and Writers if you want to handle bytes. Readers and writers are for text. One character above 127 could be transformed into three UTF-8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that sending a `String` as array of `char`, and using `String.valueOf()` to restore it is the right way.

`String` already has a mechanism to convert itself to/from bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
...
String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Try using this 2 methods to convert `String` to `byte[]` and vice versa.

Comment: Alright, will try! Any idea why sending messages doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexanderGriessel why do you think that it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, because, as I said, any data sent always includes incorrect bytes for bytes over 127...

Comment: @AlexanderGriessel as you can see from your code, they are not **bytes**, but **chars**. Bytes are signed `-128...127`. Chars are **unsigned** 2 bytes, therefore it is totally OK for the char to be `0..65535`